# Networking (P2P or Server client)

Tags: networking, p2p

Suppose we have two phones (A) and (B). And i am sharing a file from one (A) to another phone (B). But we are not sharing anything from (B) to (A). In that case which model of Networking we are using.
P2P or Server-client Network

Answer (score 0):

I think it is `Server-client Network` here. P2P is more difficult and not quite suitable for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'll first roughly clarify the notions of Client-Server model and P2P model here:

### Client-Server Model

Client-Server model is the networking model where the client initiates the communication to the server and the server responds accordingly.

##### Example

Your HTTP GET request to browse this Stackoverflow page is client-server model since your networking device first sends a GET request to the server and the server responds with the HTML page.

### P2P Model

P2P model is the one where there is a node (or multiple nodes) that work as a mediator and help networking devices (in your case phones A and B) to communicate with each other.

##### Example

Skype uses P2P model to allow networking devices (e.g. smartphones that have Skype app installed) to communicate with each other. The networking devices first establish connections with intermediate nodes and then talk to each other via those nodes.

---

Therefore, I would say your case falls into the category of P2P because the two phones A and B most likely need some intermediate nodes in order to communicate with each other unless the firewall settings and other network-related configurations of the phones can be modified to allow direct communication (which is probably not the case here). Note that the communication between A and B doesn't have to be bidirectional to be characterized as P2P.